# No matter but Authentication Fails - Java - Swing

Tags: java, swing

**I have tried all the changes but It shows invalid credentials. Please please to solve this out.**

It simply rejects the combination and i am confused about it.

It is a logical error.

I want to add Username to table once it works.

I added all packages and removed all exceptions but it doesn't work.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Authenticate extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JLabel l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8;
JPasswordField jp1,jp2;
JComboBox c1,c2,c3;
JTextField t1,t2,t3;
JTextArea ta;
JButton jb1,jb2;
String[] day = new String[31];
String[] year = new String[40];
String[] month = new String[12];
public Authenticate()
{
Container c = getContentPane();
c.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
l1 = new JLabel("Name");
l2 = new JLabel("E-mail ID");
l3 = new JLabel("Address");
l4 = new JLabel("User name");
l5 = new JLabel("Password");
l6 = new JLabel("Confirm Password");
l7 = new JLabel("DOB");
l8 = new JLabel(" ");
jp1 = new JPasswordField(10);
jp2 = new JPasswordField(10);
jp1.setEchoChar('$');
jp2.setEchoChar('*');
t1 = new JTextField(10);
t2 = new JTextField(10);
t3 = new JTextField(10);
ta = new JTextArea(3,15);
jb1 = new JButton("Submit");
jb2 = new JButton("Reset");
for(int i=0;i<31;i++)
{
day[i] = String.valueOf(i+1);
}
for(int i=0;i<35;i++)
{
year[i] = String.valueOf(i+1980);
}
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";
c1 = new JComboBox(day);
c2 = new JComboBox(month);
c3 = new JComboBox(year);
jb1.addActionListener(this);
jb2.addActionListener(this);
c.add(l1);
c.add(t1);
c.add(l2);
c.add(t2);
c.add(l3);
c.add(ta);
c.add(l4);
c.add(t3);
c.add(l5);
c.add(jp1);
c.add(l6);
c.add(jp2);
c.add(l7);
c.add(c1);
c.add(c2);
c.add(c3);
c.add(jb1);
c.add(jb2);
c.add(l8);
setSize(500,500);
setVisible(true);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
String s = ae.getActionCommand();
String s1,s2,s3;
s1 = t3.getText();
s2 = jp1.getText();
s3 = jp2.getText();
if(s.equals("Submit"))  //submit btn
{
if(s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Ghiridhar") && s2.equals("Achiever") && s2==s3)     // right credentials
l8.setText("Login Successful");
else
{
l8.setText("Invalid Credentials");
t3.setText(" ");
jp1.setText("");
jp2.setText("");

}       //else

}       //inner if
else    // reset btn
{
t1.setText(" ");
t2.setText(" ");
t3.setText(" ");
ta.setText(" ");
jp1.setText("");
jp2.setText("");
l8.setText(" ");
}       //else

}       // action fn

public static void main(String a[])
{
Authenticate a1 = new Authenticate();
}

}
```

**Please assist on this aspect.**

Comment: Please indent your code properly, reading this is torture.

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) ***"Please assist on this aspect."*** Please ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to compare text in s2 and s3 then it should be like:

`s2.equals(s3)`

instead of

`s2==s3`.

Because String is compared with `equals()`.

And please indent your code as other people suggested

Comment: My ignorance. It worked. And my Authentication successful.

Comment: That's great! I am glad that it helped.